# Wrap Label Text In Fuion Charts (Pie-Chart)

Tags: javascript, charts, label, pie-chart, fusioncharts

Length of the text is too long to fit in my column in a row

label issue

[image: 1]

is there any way to solve this issue in Fusion charts?

Below is the code for pie chart -

```
var initMemberInvestedSectorWiseCharts = function (membersInvestedSectorWiseData) {
    FusionCharts.ready(function(){
        var chartObj = new FusionCharts({
                type: 'pie2d',
                renderAt: 'members-invested-sectorwise',
                width: '100%',
                height: '400',
                dataFormat: 'json',
                dataSource: {
                    "chart": {
                        "caption": ``,
                        "subCaption": "",
                        "numberPrefix": "",
                        "showPercentInTooltip": "0",
                        "decimals": "1",
                        "useDataPlotColorForLabels": "1",
                        "theme": "fusion",
                    },
                    "data": membersInvestedSectorWiseData
                }
            }
        );
        chartObj.render();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue you can use '**manageLabelOverflow**' attribute. This attribute tries to manage overflow of data labels. If enabled, data labels are either wrapped or truncated with ellipses to prevent them from overflowing out of the chart canvas.

For more info -
[Click here](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes/pie2d)

```
manageLabelOverflow:"1",
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8c1v26L/6/)